# Convert string to tuple in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using python to call a SQL script to run in snowflake. The python script passes a tuple as a string to SQL's where clause, but how can I convert the string back to tuple in SQL?

For example, the SQL query looks like:
`where catalog_item_id in '(1180, 3190)'` whereas it suppose to be `where catalog_item_id in (1180, 3190)`.

I tried `where catalog_item_id in (select cast('(1180, 3190)' as varchar))` and `where catalog_item_id in (select replace('(1180, 3190)', '''', ''))`, none of them works. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

---

Responding to comments, my codes in python:

```
file = open(fnm, 'r')
product_list = (1180, 3190)
query = file.read().replace('{item_ids}', str(product_list))
file.close()
```

The sql query looks like

```
select 
catalog_item_id,
score
from ITEM_RECOMMENDATIONS
where catalog_item_id in '{item_ids}'
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: *The python script passes a tuple as a string to SQL's where clause* - this means that you pass it into MySQL query incorrectly. Share your code.

Comment: Just modified the question. Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the single quotes in the file?  Then look up parameterised queries, and do it properly (using `replace` or any direct string substitution is *dangerous*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html):

```
select catalog_item_id,score
from ITEM_RECOMMENDATIONS
where catalog_item_id in (select value from split_to_table(input_param, ','));
```

where input_param should be provided as: '1180,3190'

Comment: I did `catalog_item_id in (select input.value from table(split_to_table('{item_ids}', ',')) as input)`. This works perfectly. Thank you!